# Salesforce Custom Report Type on Dashboard Visibility permission

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have created a custom report type on Dashboard and Dashboard component, but this report type does not seem to be visible for users, until I give them the "Manage Custom Report Type" permission. Is it possible to make the report type visible without giving this permission? I do not want users to "Manage" the report types, also considering this also enables the dependent "View Setup and Configuration" Permission, which I definitely don't want users to have.

Comment: when you edit the report type, at the bottom there's field about status. I don't remember exact name but it'll say "In development" or "deployed". What does it say?

Comment: @eyescream It says deployed. I had checked that setting. The weird part is users are able to see other custom report types, it is just with the 'report' and 'dashboard' report types. Another point is that the users do have permissions on the reports/dashboards. It is only when I enable this specific setting to manage report types, that the report types show up in the list.

Comment: interesting. does the report type include a managed object and they might not have a license for it. Are all the custom objects in it "deployed" or in development ;) Can they see all fields / objects involved in the report type? If you give them a link to a concrete report - does it run well for them or throws any errors... If it's in a folder - do they have at least Viewer rights to it...

Comment: Has this used to work ok and broke only over this weekend? We've entered the Winter'22 sandbox preview, if you have a sandbox that stayed on Summer you could check if you're a victim of some release issues...

Comment: It is a report type on Dashboards having the join with dashboard components. So basically there is no object/field settings we are missing. The only settings we could check is the System permissions for Report/Dashboard and they have that enabled. I did not check if they were able to see a report created from it (Will try this). The interesting part is 'Manage Custom Report Type' gives them visibility. So safely assuming it is not some other setting that is missing. This is in Prod and so still on Summer.